# Digitally sign token with RSA-SHA1 Base64 encryption

Tags: delphi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Free Encryption library for Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402380/free-encryption-library-for-delphi)

I am trying to interface with Google Services using AuthSub:
[AuthSub Authentication](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/AuthSub.html)

In the documentation it states this:

> The signature for the secure token. This value must be a signature
>   made  by the private key corresponding to the certificate provided
>   during  registration. It must be encoded in BASE64, and must use the
>   SHA-1  with RSA using PKCS#1 padding algorithm.

I have used openssl to create public/private keys and have successfully uploaded (I think) my certificate to google.  What component can I use to accomplish the digitally signing of the token?

Thanks.

Comment: Please don't use a "quote block" instead of "code block" for the documentation paragraph you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently implemented some of the OpenSSL API in Delphi based on the work by Marco Ferrante at http://www.disi.unige.it/person/FerranteM/delphiopenssl/. There are some good samples on the site too.
Take a look at the EVP_Sign... functions.

Comment: Thanks - I will check this out.  I think most of my problems at this point are a lack of understanding how encryptition works.

Comment: I was in the same situation about a month ago. After a lot of Googling and reading the OpenSSL docs I think I know a lot more than I did! If you're using a unicode Delphi version then you need to change the PChar definitions for something like PAnsiChar or PByte - I found PByte to be preferable once I'd learned how to use TEncoding and TBytes. However for the Base64 bit I'd just use the Jedi JCL (or DCPCrypt).