# Simple digital signature using delphi

Tags: delphi, digital-signature

I am looking for a simple solution to generate a pair of keys (public/private) encrypt/hash a string and then be able to check if the string was encrypted/hashed using the public key.

Is there a simple solution for this (CryptoAPI)?

I am looking for a starting point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a look at [Turbopower Lockbox](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tplockbox/) which is open sourced a while ago. I think the `RSA sign & verify` is what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this has been asked and answered before, lots of good feedback in this thread:
[Free Encryption library for Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402380/free-encryption-library-for-delphi)

Answer (score 0):

LockBox3 or Spring4Delphi libraries